# Programming Python: Using Dictionaries to isolate data

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to complete an assignment using python. 
The goal is to use dictionaries to parse a .txt file and isolate the time and temp. To place them in a dictionary, and to then find the highest temp and its corresponding time.

I have completed the assignment, however I can't figure out how to make it print ONLY the highest. Instead I'm printing the top three.

[pycharm output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SK1Aq.png)

```
fname = raw_input("Enter the file name: ")

try:
    fhand = open(fname)
except:
    print "The file can not be opened."
    exit()

climate = dict()        #creates dictionary

count = 0
largest = None  # Iteration variable to find highest temp

high = 0
for line in fhand:
    count += 1              #count variable to get rid of line 1
    if count == 1:      #may be causing it to iterate 3x????
        continue

    words = line.split()            # splits into tokens
    time = words[0] + words[1]      # combines time and am/pm
    climate[time] = words[2]        # matches time to temp making key-value pair

for key in climate:
        if climate[key] > largest:    # Iterates through key-value's finding largest and placing it in largest container
            largest = climate[key]

            print 'The highest temperatures occurred at', key, 'reaching', largest, 'Fahrenheit.'

fhand.close()
```

Comment: define `key` before the loop so it is in scope outside the loop, and don't print within the loop, print after the `for` loop ends.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I edited the structure of the question to make it a bit clearer. I recommend instead of posting an image link to your IDE output, you edit the question to show the output as text in the question . Also @sberry suggestion is on point.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
high_key = None
largest = 0
for key in climate:
        if climate[key] > largest:    # Iterates through key-value's finding largest and placing it in largest container
            largest = climate[key]
            high_key = key

if high_key:
    print 'The highest temperatures occurred at', high_key, 'reaching', largest, 'Fahrenheit.'
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That was bugging the hell out of me. so my variables  "high" and "largest" needed to switch values, can you tell me the difference between using zero and none? The rest I understand whats happening.

Comment: Setting largest to 0 assumes that the temperatures are positive, so that some temp will over write the initial value. I think None would work better, since it would handle negative values. Personally, I would prefer to initialize `largest = float('-inf')` because I think that makes intent clearer.

Comment: Ahh okay that makes sense. Thank you. I'll keep playing around with it.